# How do you write set membership in SAS?

Tags: sas

Suppose we want to check whether a variable is not in the set of numbers {1,2,3}. How would you do this in SAS? Here is the code:

```
data test;
if x ^= {1,2,3} then x = NA;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if not (X in (1,2,3)) then call missing(x);
```

You can do this a few other ways but this is typically most common.

Comment: I prefer these variations myself: `x = ifn(x in (1,2,3),x,.);` or `if X not in (1,2,3) then call missing(x);`.   The first is nice because you can immediately see that the line of code is performing an assignment and you can stop reading there if you don't care about the value of the variable.  With an `if` statement you need to read not only the comparison, but the action being performed afterwards.

Comment: As I commented on another (now deleted) answer, I believe `not in` isn't really proper.  In particular because I've seen it confuse quite a few people not understanding why they can't use not that way in some other contexts.

Comment: That answer should probably not be deleted, fwiw.

Comment: Hmm I've been using `not in` for so long I'm no longer able to see how it could be confusing =)  I always preferred it because it's more 'natural', ie. sounds more like the spoken English language. I do understand what you are saying though...

Comment: It's not confusing in itself, it's confusing because it leads to people misunderstanding how `not` can/should be used.

Comment: Ahh ok.  So for example you can say `not in` but you can't say `not >`... fair enough...

Comment: Oddly enough, you *can* say that, which surprised me.  More along the lines of people trying to be too 'plain english' with their logical statements, e.g., "x not = 1 or 4" which seems to be automatic for non-programmers.  I tend to prefer to teach very strict usage of the boolean operators to avoid that kind of error.

Comment: Haha I should have tested it prior to using it as an example... that's pretty interesting even if I will never use that syntax again.